# How to keep the non-overlapping parts when aligning images?

Tags: image-processing, image

I would like to stitch together a pair of images. For example:

```
imgOriginal=ImageTake[ExampleData[{"TestImage","Aerial"}],{1,-2},{2,-1}];
img1=ImageTake[imgOriginal,{0,160}];
img2=ImageTake[imgOriginal,{-160,-1}];
```

[image]

`ImageAlign` successfully registers these, but of course it only returns the part of `img2` that overlaps with `img1`.

```
img2a = ImageAlign[img1, img2];
ImageCompose[img1, {Colorize[img2a], 0.25}]
```

[image]

To stitch the images together, I need to keep the entire area of `img2`. I can derive a transformation to align the two images, then apply it to `img2`:

```
ImageTransformation[img2,FindGeometricTransform[img2,img1,TransformationClass->"Rigid"][[2]],DataRange->Full]
```

[image]

But using `PlotRange->All` to show the entire image area appears to effectively un-transform the image so they no longer align.

```
img2it=ImageTransformation[img2,FindGeometricTransform[img2,img1,TransformationClass->"Rigid"][[2]],DataRange->Full,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

```
ImageCompose[img1,{Colorize[img2it],0.25}]
```

[image]

How can I retain the entire non-overlapping area of both images when registering them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the result of `FindGeometricTransform` to adjust the `PlotRange`.
Starting with the same images:

```
imgOriginal = ImageTake[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial"}], {1, -2}, {2, -1}];
img1 = ImageTake[imgOriginal, {0, 160}];
img2 = ImageTake[imgOriginal, {-160, -1}];
```

Finding the transformation with

```
tr = FindGeometricTransform[img1, img2, TransformationClass -> "Translation"];
```

using it to tramsform `img2`

```
img2it = ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img2, tr[[2]], DataRange -> Full, 
 PlotRange -> Transpose[{tr[[2]][{0, 0}], ImageDimensions[img2]}], 
 Masking -> All, Background -> White]
```

> [image: img2it]

and to position the overlay

```
ImageCompose[img2it, {Colorize[img1], 0.3}, 
  Round[(ImageDimensions[img2it] - tr[[2]][{1, 1}])/2]]
```

> [image: composedImg]

Comparing the result with the original image:

```
GraphicsRow[{%, imgOriginal}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

> [image: comparison]