# Aligning transformed images to form a mosaic

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to align and stitch together these images to form a mosaic:

[image]
[image]

It's a similar problem as this one:

[How to keep the non-overlapping parts when aligning images?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76953/how-to-keep-the-non-overlapping-parts-when-aligning-images)

However, (and I may not have properly understood that answer) I haven't been able to get that approach to work with these images. I want to get image 1 and all of a transformed image 2 nicely overlaid.

So to design a simpler test case, I created two images like this:
[image]

[image]

This is the result I'm trying to achieve (done here manually, with image borders added to highlight that the two images are whole but superimposed):

[image]

So I tried find the geometric transform, and then applying it:

[image]

i23 has the correct rotation and translation to nicely overlay i21, but how do I achieve the final overlaying of the images to get the desired result?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Daryl - I don't have time to post a properly done answer, but just taking the example images and applying the code shown in the documentation for `FindGeometricTransform` works directly *if the images are rotated -90 degrees* .... so there's something in there I'd venture that specifies/limits the way matches are found/evaluated. I don't do much (if any) such image work, so can't offer much more, but perhaps that will spur ideas.

Comment: I think `FindGeometricTransform` is finding the right transform of `i20` to match it up with `i21`, and `ImageTransformation` is applying it properly to `i20` to yield `i23`, but I don't know how to superimpose the transformed image `i23` over the top of image `i21` to yield the desired result shown manually stitched above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a way to achieve my desired result. Taking the original images as i1 and i2, I reduced them to 658x370, just to keep them manageable.

```
In[3]:= ImageDimensions[i1][[1]]
Out[3]= 658

In[4]:= xpad = ImageDimensions[i1][[1]]*0.5
Out[4]= 329.

In[5]:= ypad = ImageDimensions[i1][[2]]*0.5
Out[5]= 185.
```

Then I padded the first image to make room for the second one to be added.

```
i1pad = ImagePad[i1, {{0, 0}, {0, ypad}}]
```

[image]

I used ImageAlign to find a transform that would align i2 with i1, and applied it to i2.

```
i2tr = ImageAlign[i1pad, i2, Method -> "Keypoints", TransformationClass -> "Rigid", Background -> Transparent]
```

[image]

Then I created an image by overlaying the transformed image on top of the padded i1.

```
ImageCompose[i1pad, i2tr]
```

[image]

That's what I set out to do, and I learned a lot, but my experience has been that Mathematica Home 10.1 can't handle the original 5MP images on my MacBook Pro with a 2.8GHz dual-core i7. It never seems to finish, while using hardly anything of the 16GB available memory and 30% of the CPU. I'll need to look at other tools to handle the 50 or so 5MP images I'm wanting to stitch.